# How to jsonify a object with new values?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have some object with different atributes' types: `String`,`Float`,`LocalDate` and so on. To turn this object into a json `String`, I use (`com.google.gson.Gson`)

```
gson.toJson(object);
```

But now I want to add a `String` to it:

```
{
  "warning" : "old",
  --Jsonified Object--
}
```

How can I add specific key-values data into a object without doing boilerplate code or creating a new object that has a new attribute plus the old ones?

Comment: Do you have control over the source code of the class of `object`?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't want to modify it since this would break some attribute pattern I created with another entities that don't need to be jsonified. I would like to add a key-value as the last thing before sending it via REST requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `com.google.gson.JsonObject` class to add extra fields.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)gson.toJsonTree(object, YourObjects.class);
jsonObject.addProperty("warning" , "old"); // add required extra fields
String json = gson.toJson(jsonObject); // create son string
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this without creating a new class or modify the current is to work with maps. Of course it still needs some boilerplate, but you can create a method where you do all this.

With Gson starting from the already generated json you can create a map, modify this map and then create the json again.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Map<String, Object> map = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType());

// here you process the map, e.g. put or remove keys
map.put("warning", "old");

String json = gson.toJson(myMap);
```

If you do not want to start from the created JSON I recomend to transform your object in a map with jackson object mapper and then process the map and create the json. You should use another library like jackson because Gson does not provice a way to transform a object to a map.